Can We Use Indefinite Articles or the Zero Article in Highly Specific Noun Phrases?
Edit: Here's some further context for my examples, as I think some answers are losing focus. Imagine all the examples below are written in a past-tense narrative book (in the middle of a chapter, not the opening) or spoken in conversation while the speaker recounts a past event (which is effectively another form of storytelling). The person reading or hearing these sentences has no contextual clues except for what they've read or been told. (The amount of context they have is outlined beneath each example.)
Consider the following examples:

[1] Jack approached a man who was standing by the door.

In Example 1, let's say that 'the door' has been previously mentioned, but this is the first mention of the 'man.' Let's also say that I, the writer/speaker, know that there was only one man standing by the door.

[2] James approached a group that he recognised as his friends from high school.

In Example 2, let's say the 'group' hasn't been mentioned.

[3] Sarah looked at a stack of papers on the table.

In Example 3, let's say that 'the table' has been previously mentioned, but the 'stack' is new information. Let's also say that I know there was only one stack of papers on the table.
In all of these examples, I (as a native speaker) feel that the use of the indefinite article 'a' is correct; however, I also acknowledge that all of these noun phrases refer to very specific entities: the only man standing by a specific door, the only group that could be recognised as 'his friends from high school,' and the only stack of papers on the desk.
Throughout my research into article usage, it's often said that the definite article is used for defined entities, not just those that have been mentioned previously in the discourse. On this forum, most of the posts I've seen talking about indefinite articles give generic examples, such as 'I saw a man with dark hair.' In this example, it's obvious (to me, at least) that we wouldn't use 'the' when mentioning the 'man with dark hair' for the first time, as there are many men with dark hair in the world. This doesn't apply to my examples, which reference unique entities that have been highly specified by relative clauses and prepositional phrases.
My question, as stated in the title of this question, is whether we can (or should) use the indefinite articles (or the zero article, if required) for examples such as 1, 2, and 3. My gut feeling is that the answer is yes; my reasoning is that although the noun phrases are very specific entities, only the writer/speaker knows this. The reader/listener is not aware that only one man was standing by the door or that there was only one stack of papers on the table, so if we used the definite article, they may feel inclined to question what I'm referring to.
Edit 2: Here's a real-life example from The New York Times: 'I was alone in the room except for a man sitting by the windows.' This demonstrates the use of the indefinite article 'a' for an entity that can't be one of a wider category; there can't be multiple men sitting by these specific windows—unless, that is, we look at it from a past and future perspective, where someone may have sat or will sit there.

"Jack approached the man who was standing by the door" would be fine. It depends if the man is going to be the topic and you want to emphasise that it's a particular man, or if it's just a passing mention and he's not going to be discussed further, as well as whether there was one man there or more. Whether you use "the" isn't purely about whether the entity was mentioned before, but despite what rules are commonly given, there's often a degree of choice.

What works in a narrative might not work in a conversation. If I say to a coworker, "The boss was speaking to the man in the green shirt." and there was no such man visible nearby,  the coworker might reply "What man? What are you talking about?"

@StuartF, thanks for your input :) I completely agree it isn't about whether it was mentioned previously, as I touched upon in my post. Additionally, I specified that in my example, the writer/speaker knows there's only one man, not multiple. I'm not sure I entirely agree with your topic idea; that could work if this sentence was (or was near to) the opening of a story, perhaps, as we're dropping the reader into it, but I think in the middle of a long piece of text or a conversation, it could be jarring.

If you're asking for writing advice, I suggest presenting larger passages, as the context matters and the "rules" of what sounds most natural cannot be boiled down to simple statements. If you're looking for an explanation of how English speakers use definiteness, there is a wealth of linguistics literature on the subject (suffice it to say that there are many considerations and subtleties!).

In contexts such as...

"See who's at the door"
"Put it on the table"
"Look out of the window"

...it would normally be "unusual" to use the indefinite article (a instead of the), even if there were several doors, tables, or windows in the current context (none of which had been referred to in earlier conversation).
Often, it's not so much that the definite article implies reference to one (obvious and/or specific) door / table / window. It's more that using the indefinite article implies there are / may be several, but it doesn't matter which one.
If you don't specifically want that highlighted implication, it's often more natural to stick with the definite article anyway. Hence you're more likely (especially in recent decades) to say...

"I travel to work on the train"
...rather than...
"I travel to work on a train"

...because as a regular commuter you'd normally catch a specific train to get to work.

Thanks for your answer, @FumbleFingers. I think I may need to specify the context of my examples, as while I agree with your assessment in certain scenarios, I don't think it works if you were explaining a past event to someone or writing a past-tense narrative (that's how I'm viewing my examples). Your first three examples imply that the listener knows what's being referred to, hence the imperative clauses. Your second examples demonstrate a very specific usage of 'the,' which is discussed at length in different grammars I've read, another example being 'I'm going to get the bus.'

In retrospect, I'm not sure why i bothered to answer at all. All I really meant to say was "Don't assume the choice of definite / indefinite article is easily described in a few sentences". If I were you I wouldn't even bother trying to formally identify "rules". Just use whichever you like best yourself in any given context unless and until someone points out you made the wrong choice. But don't bother with reasons - just vary your choice until no-one picks you up on it. That's how all Anglophone children learned this - no kindergarten teacher ever formally told them the "rules"

@FumbleFingers Hi! I upvoted your good answer!


... these noun phrases refer to very specific entities: the only man standing by a specific door, the only group that could be recognised as 'his friends from high school,' and the only stack of papers on the desk.

You have a basic misunderstanding.  The entities themselves have no intrinsic specificity. It is the utterance that presents them as specific or not.
If I present someone as specific "out of the blue" in a conversation, someone who has not been introduced and is not visible to the listener, there's cognitive dissonance for the listener. Let's say there's a water-cooler in the office and I'm speaking to a coworker:

The man in the deerstalker hat was standing by the water-cooler.

If there is no such man in a deerstalker hat in view, and nobody in the office wears one regularly, my coworker may think I'm hallucinating or that they misheard me or that I'm telling some sort of joke.
Conversely, if I present someone as the opposite, lacking specificity when they are known and present, there's cognitive dissonance for the listener.  The boss is standing by the water cooler, and I say:

A man in a blue shirt is standing by the water cooler.

My coworker might say "You mean the boss? Why are you referring to him as 'a man in a blue shirt'?  Are you stoned? Having some kind of episode? What?"
If the thing has  specificity, that specificity exists in the mind of the listener. It is an epistemological status, not an ontological one.

Does that mean you agree with my assessment that the indefinite article is correct because the reader/listener is not aware of the entity, even though I know there's no other possible person I could be referring to? I think the key difference between my examples and your 'deerstalker' example is that if I said 'a man in a deerstalker hat,' we know there are likely other men in deerstalker hats somewhere in the world. I've specified in Example 1 that the reader/listener is aware of 'the door,' so that prevents the interpretation that multiple men are standing by that specific door.

If you say "a man was in my way", speaking of a situation where the listener was not present, you're not specifying which man it was; you're simply saying, as it were, "some male member of the species homo sapiens, identity unknown to me, was in my way".  You could go on to say "The man was large."  Your listener knows when you say "the man" that you are centering the focus on him. The listener is aware of your focus, not of the man per se, not of the ontological entity. But if the listener is present with you, the listener can map your focus to a real observable entity.
